# Visual Studio 2019, UI test video capture using runsettings on Azure Devops, wmv 0 bytes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, video-capture

Has anyone got to work on video capture? The video capture is working fine locally using runsettings file. But, When I tried run UI test cases on Azure Devops pipeline its creates WMV 0 bytes and recordedmedia.trmx of 1 kb in attachment.It didn't capture any data in wmv file. It captures data for wmv only when logged into agents while running UI test cases on devops pipeline.Is there any solution for this?

```
<DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" 
assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
```

I tried running in  two different ways with logging into agent and other way is without logging into agents. It produced two different results

logged into self hosted agent it created data 2828 kb wmv file
[image]

Didn't logged into self hosted agent and created a 0KB wmv file
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Visual Studio test` task to run tests, video of the test can be captured and is automatically available as an attachment to the test result. For this, you must configure the video data collector in a `.runsettings` file and this file must be specified in the task settings.

```
<DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
        <!--Video data collector was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
        <Configuration>
          <!-- Set "sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase" to "false" to add video attachments to failed tests only -->
          <MediaRecorder sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase="true"  xmlns="">           
            <ScreenCaptureVideo bitRate="512" frameRate="2" quality="20" />
          </MediaRecorder>
        </Configuration>
</DataCollector>
```

[image]

Also, you must set up your agent to run as a process instead of a service, you could check your agent.

Comment: How's your issue going?